# as.yearqtr in R starting from December instead of January

Tags: r, time-series, raster, zoo

I have a raster time series created as a zoo onbect. I am able to aggregate quarterly means but I want the aggregates from December-February,March-May,June-August and September to Novermber. How can I make this possible please?
Normal R code is:

```
library(raster)
library(zoo)
C <- raster(nrows=30, ncols=30)
C[] <- 1:ncell(C)
O <- raster(nrows=30, ncols=30)
O[] <- 1:ncell(O)
CO1 <- stack(C,C,C,C,O,O,O)
m <- seq(as.Date('2009-12-15'), as.Date('2010-06-15'), 'month')
CO2 <- setZ(CO1,m)
CN <- zApply(CO2, by=as.yearqtr, fun=mean)
```

This would yield a quarterly mean for December,January-March and April-June.
What I want is a mean for Dec-Feb, Mar-May,June.

Comment: Example code should be reproducible which means that all inputs needed to run it should be provided.

Comment: I have expanded the code a bit

Comment: To be reproducible it also needs all library statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
zApply(CO2, by=round(unclass(getZ(CO2)) * 12 + 1) %/%3, fun=mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stackApply`, which is conceptually similar to `tapply`. Not as nifty as `zApply` because it can be more laborious to set up the indices you need.

```
stackApply(CO2, c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3), fun=mean)
```

Comment: Thanks RobertH. Thing is this example is quite regular. The actual data set had a few missing months which I dont want to interpolate. For example if for one year there is only data for december I want it to return the mean for december , January february, which basically same as december.

Comment: I do not understand your response. `stackApply` is effectively the same thing as `zApply`. Which one is easier depends on how your data is organized